# 2D physics calculate time to reach a point with linear drag

Tags: box2d, game-physics

I'm wanting to apply a force to a rigidbody so it arrives at/intercepts a point at a given time (Box2D in Unity). The system is currently set up so one unit of force propels the rigibody one unit of distance with drag stopping it at this distance. Thus a force of 10 will move the rb ten units until it comes to a stop. Force 5 will move it 5 units in *t1* time, while force 10 will move it 5 units in *t2* time, notably less than half the time.

What I need is to be able to say, "this rb needs to travel *x* units in *t* seconds, so apply a force *m*," and get a force m that'll satisfy this.

Box2D's linear drag provides non-linear acceleration that I can't map to any usable function. How can a generate a method to return the required force m?

Edit:
In a football game, to pass to a moving player you need the trajectory of the ball with drag to intercept the trajectory of the receiving player travelling at constant velocity. This pass can be slow, and need to be further ahead of the receiver, or faster and with less lookahead. I can select a time and compute the distance, but not the force needed to get the ball to travel that distance in that time with drag in effect.

Comment: Can you describe more specificaly what exactly are you trying to achieve? For example, if the body is the lift that should travel with a constant speed, then you should consider using a kinematic body and SetLinearVelocity to move the body. If the body is a projectile (for example a grenade) that should reach the desired point in the desired time, then you probably need to calculate the trajectory and move the body along it, also manually, without relying on the box2d solver

Comment: I'll update with details

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I encountered same problem as yours and my advice is to avoid applying force - instead of this think about applying an **impulse**.

```
    void applyLinearImpulse(Vector2 impulse, Vector2 point, boolean wake)
```

Box2d **linearImpulse** modificates the body's velocity immediately. When we are talking about [velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) **not force** it's really simple to calculate time when having some velocity, or velocity when need to achieve some position in time. Linear impulse cares on mass etc on its own so you don't need to care about it.

I recommend you a [nice article about box2d applicable forces](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/16/understanding-box2d-applicable-forces/) that will it easier to understand the topic.